# Why does the word "incident" have a negative connotation associated with it?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I'm trying to find why we consistently use the word "incident" with a negative connotation. All definitions of the word state something to the tune of:

> an individual occurrence or event.

By this definition, I should be able to say "That birthday was quite an incident!" right? However, if I used that sentence in a conversation, someone would think a bad thing happened at the birthday.

Which brings me to my question, why do we use incident with a negative connotation?

Comment: Because that is its typical usage.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm asking how we ended up with this usage, I'm aware that's the typical usage.

Comment: Because of the incident of the chicken and the egg.

Comment: Or perhaps because of [The Bedford Incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bedford_Incident).

Answer (score 1):

M-W cites the negative connotation of [incident](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incident) as third:

> 3 : an action likely to lead to grave consequences especially in diplomatic matters.
>
> - a serious border incident

The above connotation is an [euphemistic usage](https://www.etymonline.com/word/incident) from the beginning of the 20th century:

> Euphemistic meaning "event that might trigger a crisis or political unrest" first attested 1913. (Etymonline)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the definition of "incident" has shifted significantly over the years.  It's [original meaning](https://www.etymonline.com/word/incident) was "something which occurs casually in connection with something else", but it is now commonly regarded more as a (relatively random) "accident" whose cause is not really important.

With the original meaning, the term was naturally applied (somewhat euphemistically) to situations with bad outcomes, as a good outcome would tend to be described as beneficial.

(Note that a birthday is only an "incident" when one considers the prior lifetime of the subject.)